# What is the best distance for saplings to grow?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm working on a tree farm in Minecraft and I've been trying with all of my other worlds but I can never get the exact number of blocks. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My tree farm is not growing even with bonemeal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174650/my-tree-farm-is-not-growing-even-with-bonemeal)

Comment: @toroid Not a duplicate because this is Bedrock Edition and that is Java Edition.

Comment: @pppery my assumption was that the logic was the same across the two games, but you're right that they're distinct games.

Answer (score 0):

About 3-5 blocks should be enough space for you trees to grow quickly. Not that long ago, I decided to make a natural-looking tree farm (Pretty much just a circle of cobblestone with spammed oak saplings inside) and found that the trees could be grown quickly even if they were 2 or 3 blocks apart.